# FireBreath IE ActiveX wont send auth cookie

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, cookies, activex, firebreath

I am not sure whether it is an issue of FireBreath or an ActiveX specific thing or I have just forgotten something.

I want to a download a file in my plugin using a derivative of FB::DefaultBrowserStreamHandler, and FB::BrowserHost::createStream(). The file is only accessable if my http request is authenticated by a cookie.

The built FireBreath plugin is working under Chrome and FF, but not under IE. The thing is that under IE no session cookie is sent when analyzing the requests with Fiddler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature that isn't supported the way you need it to be in FireBreath's activex implementation of browserstreams.  You'd have to go into the code and find a way to add support for setting the cookie manually, I'm afraid. The reason it works in npapi browsers is that the browser itself provides an API for making the request, which means it will provide proxy info and cookies.  In IE we have to emulate that, and that emulation doesn't get the cookies.